# Image "fade" in / out (Not opacity)

Tags: delphi, bitmap, bezier

I want to "fade" in / out an image. But not opacity-wise.

Pictures say more than words:

Original image:

[image]

Desired image:

[image]

How can I do that programatically? Not the way like "use Bitmap.Canvas" but the mathematical approach. ("For dummies" if possible ... :D)

I want the image to have a fade-in / -out area, not linear increasing but "curvy". I guess it has something to do with `Bezier` curves? If yes, how would I setup the points to get a curve like that?

Or what would be your approach here?

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is roughly how you would go about doing it (as you said, you're looking for the logic and not the full implementation)

1. **Create the basic shape outline:** Create a partial sine-wave, such that the semi-period (half-wavelength: P1 = L/2) equals the length (x-coordinate size) of your image.
2. **Add Overtones:** Add to it another sine-function. This time with wavelength given by `P2 = P1 / 2 + rnd` where `rnd` is a random real number in the interval `(-P1/4 , +P1 / 4)`
3. **Repeat:** Now P2 becomes the new P1.

That way you can generate the 'wavy-waves' by modulating the main wave and you will get the top boundary.

You can change the sign and get the lower boundary.

The word you might be looking for (for the shape, i.e.) is **Overtones**. You could look up more on generating overtones for optics or acoustics.

This example for adding overtones to a straight line would give a better idea. The code above adds up these sinusoidal waves of randomly shortening periods to create the wave-on-wave effect ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_tuning))
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tips and keywords. Going to figure that out and will give feedback later on. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks again, **hnk**. You got me the right ideas. :)

I did a little work and ended up with this:

```
procedure GenerateOverlayEdges(ABitmap: TBitmap; ARadiusX, ARadiusY: Integer);
const
  MAX_ANGLE = 90;
var
  ShapePosition, ShapeIndex, ShapesCount,
  Angle, X, Y, RadiusX, RadiusY, CenterY: Integer;
  PolyPoints: Array of TPoint;
begin
  ABitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
  ABitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;

  //ABitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := clWhite;
  //ABitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;

  RadiusX := ARadiusX;
  RadiusY := ARadiusY;
  CenterY := Round(ABitmap.Height / 2);
  ShapesCount := Ceil(CenterY / RadiusY);

  for ShapePosition := 1 to 4 do // 1 = TopLeft, 2 = BottomLeft, 3 = TopRight, 4 = BottomRight
    for ShapeIndex := 0 to ShapesCount - 1 do  // Index of current "stair"
      begin
        Finalize(PolyPoints);
        SetLength(PolyPoints, MAX_ANGLE + 1);
        for Angle := 0 to MAX_ANGLE do
          begin
            case ShapePosition of
              1, 3:
              begin
                RadiusX := Abs(RadiusX);
                RadiusY := Abs(RadiusY);                
              end;
              2, 4:
              begin
                RadiusX := Abs(RadiusX);
                RadiusY := -Abs(RadiusY);
              end;
            end;

            X := Trunc(RadiusX * Cos(Angle * 2 * Pi / 360));
            Y := Trunc(RadiusY * Sin(Angle * 2 * Pi / 360));
            case ShapePosition of
              1:
              begin
                X := X + ShapeIndex * RadiusX;
                Y := Y + CenterY - RadiusY - ShapeIndex * RadiusY;
              end;
              2:
              begin
                X := X + ShapeIndex * RadiusX;
                Y := Y + CenterY - RadiusY + ShapeIndex * Abs(RadiusY);
              end;
              3:
              begin
                X := ABitmap.Width - X - ShapeIndex * Abs(RadiusX);
                Y := Y + CenterY - RadiusY - ShapeIndex * RadiusY;
              end;
              4:
              begin
                X := ABitmap.Width - X - ShapeIndex * Abs(RadiusX);
                Y := Y + CenterY + Abs(RadiusY) + ShapeIndex * Abs(RadiusY);
              end;
            end;

            // Add points as part of a Polyon
            PolyPoints[Angle] := Point(X, Y);
          end;

        // Set Y to the Y borders for the very first and last point of the polygon so we will get a "closed" shape
        case ShapePosition of
          1, 3:  
          begin
            PolyPoints[0] := Point(PolyPoints[0].X, 0);
            PolyPoints[Angle - 1] := Point(PolyPoints[Angle - 1].X, 0);
          end;
          2, 4:  
          begin
            PolyPoints[0] := Point(PolyPoints[0].X, ABitmap.Height);
            PolyPoints[Angle - 1] := Point(PolyPoints[Angle - 1].X, ABitmap.Height);
          end;
        end;

        // Draw the poly points ... and fill the background at the same time
        ABitmap.Canvas.Polygon(PolyPoints);  
      end;

  Finalize(PolyPoints);
end;
```

Usage:

```
var
    Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
    Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
        Bmp.LoadFromFile('C:\Temp\Osc 2.bmp'); // Original Oscilloscope Image
        GenerateOverlayEdges(Bmp, 15, 20);
        Bmp.SaveToFile('C:\Temp\Osc 3.bmp');
    finally
        Bmp.Free;
    end;
end;
```

By changing the `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` parameters of the `GenerateOverlayEdges` function I can adjust the results:

8x8:

[image]

15x20:

[image]

20x10:

[image]

Comment: Certainly looks like what you wanted earlier. I see that you've modified the logic I suggested to use circular overlays to create a similar effect. Looks good.